# Is make-up haram?

Tags: halal-haram, cosmetics

Tattooing and plucking your eyebrows is haram because you are changing the way you look. When you apply make-up you also change the way you look. You put make-up on to make yourself look 'better'. Is this not the same as when you shape your eyebrows? Does that mean make-up is haram too?

Comment: Yes it is the same, scholars have different opinions on the reason for this prohibition some of them say it is because with make up or plucking your eyebrow you make yourself look better and therefore you are cheating, that's why some allow it for married women and forbade it for unmarried ones.

Answer (score 1):

Make up for Husband is Acceptable.

Makeup for others is Forbidden.

The beauty of Women is for their husbands.

The ayat in Quran which advices our prophet (sallallaahu 'alaihi wasallam) to watch over his family members rightly is also the right instruction for his ummah to follow as Sahabaye Keram (Radhiallahu ta'ala anhum) did in their life.

> And stay in your houses, and do not display yourselves like that of the times of ignorance, and perform As-Salat (IqamatasSalat), and give Zakat and obey Allah and His Messenger. Allah wishes only to remove ArRijs (evil deeds and sins, etc.) from you, O members of the family (of the Prophet SAW), and to purify you with a thorough purification.
>
> > Surat-al-Ahzab
> >
> > > ayat 33
> > >
> > > link: [Surat-al-Ahzab:33](http://legacy.quran.com/33/33)

Comment: What about eyebrow plucking for husband satisfaction?

Comment: I mentioned Make up is acceptable for women to do if it is for husbands.

Comment: Now, if the ingredients of make up contains haraam, then, using those sorts of make up is also haraam. As our prophet (PBUH) cursed upon those who pluck their eyebrows and who want to pluck their eyebrows, it has been decided that Plucking eyebrows are haraam.

Comment: So, even for plucking eyebrows for the satisfaction of husbands cannot overthrow the curse of Rasulallaah (Sallallaahu 'alaihi wasallam).  So, eyebrow plucking for husband satisfaction is not permissible. It's a major sin for both men and women though the hadith was for women because the women of Jahiliyya (Period of Ignorance) used to tattoo on their body as well as remove the eyebrows.  [Hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/37/181)

Comment: Yh but there is always a clear reason behind everything and I am after the reason as I have not found the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Plucking your eyebrows, if full, then Haram. If some extra ones, then as far as women are concerned, it's fine. 
And make-up is also fine but it's for the husband only and not for random people. 
Hope this helps. 
And no, make-up and eyebrow plucking completely aren't the same. Scholars agree that if it's for beautification, then it's allowed, in which case make-up and eyebrow plucking (only the extra ones) are allowed only for the husband's satisfaction and not anyone else.

Comment: Either way you are doing it for beauty purposes. Can you give a source for eyebrow plucking even if it is just extra ones..being allowed in Islam, What is considered extra because most people pluck but not all of their eye brows obviously.

Comment: I cannot quote the Hadith. But there are lots of authentic books regarding these. This is a very huge topic. I have seen the Q and A sessions regarding these answered by PhD Scholars who follow the Quran and Sunnah. As they said, am saying that same answer, for beautification, it's okay, but there is a huge discussion regarding this. But plucking few eyebrows are allowed as most scholars of today agree with, because the questions asked to them were exactly like you asked, and am answering just like they said.

Comment: I mean make up is allowed to satisfy ur husband then why not plucking eyebrows for the same reason? I have not come across any scholar who says it is allowed. plus there are hadiths that say it is not allowed but doesnt say why

Comment: Please read the comment again, I mistakenly posted it without typing completely.

Comment: That's what am saying, it's allowed for beautification, removing the extra hairs. Now how much allowed, why allowed and how allowed, you need to read the books and understand that in depth. I just gave you the straightforward answer. Yes, I also believed it's not allowed, but after seeing several authentic lectures by PhD Scholars of Islam, am convinced and know that it's allowed like I mentioned in details in the main answer. For other information on Hadith and all, you need to read the books written on these topics.

Comment: And the Hadiths you spoke of isn't authentic. If they were, then it wouldn't be allowed.